# Exporting UV maps to Gimp

Tags: uv, export

I'm following a tutorial on exporting UV maps to Photoshop.  I only have Gimp, but I figured the principals are the same.  I went to UVs -> Export UV layout.  Then I saved the PNG file to my computer.  Then I went into Gimp and opened the PNG file.  But all I see is an alpha background in the proportions and scale of my UV map.  There is no UV map, no colors, nothing.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I figured it out.  I needed to select the whole UV layout with A before exporting.